# 1990 Nissan Maxima Heater blower motor

Tags: nissan, maxima, heater-blower

My girlfriend has a 1990 Nissan Maxima, and the heater blower motor is not working properly.
 I replaced the  variable resistor switch in the dashboard  because the other one looked a little bit burnt.  that made it start blowing a little bit better.  For some reason it still doesn't blow out air very hard. I'm wondering if there's too much resistance somewhere in the system, because it seems to have a low amperage.

Comment: It could be a failing motor.

Comment: @Moab +1. As Moab is saying, certainly could be the motor failing. It's now a 30 year old motor, and who knows how many hours of run-time it's racked up! If you can access the blower, take a whiff to see if it smells burn and/or give it a spin to see if it rolls smoothly and well.

Comment: I just finished ordering a motor for it. Thanks guys!  I took it ( the Maxima) back up to the  College  today, where I am  an automotive technology student.  I opened up the Identifix program that we have there,  and found all of the resistors and all of the components connected to the heating system.  My lab partner and I also took apart the entire dashboard and put all the parts in the trunk.  Everything is working perfectly, except the heater blower motor, so you guys must be right, it's just old.